# How can I generate dynamic SQL in WhereScape (on Greenplum)?

Tags: postgresql, greenplum

We have a table of business rules that define column names and tests to perform - null/populated, >=, <=, etc., and I want to create a procedure or function that implements these rules dynamically. Can I do this in WhereScape RED, or do I have to create a custom PostgreSQL function to build the SQL, and pass a record into it? I'm not even sure if PostgreSQL functions can take a generic record input.

Answer (score 0):

You can create custom logic (called Transformations) within columns in WhereScape RED, so this may be possible.

However, I would highly recommend you raise this on the Wherescape forum (https://www.wherescape.com/support/forums/) as you'll be more likely to get a quicker response.